# If I compare two values over a period of time, is it reasonable to attempt a correlation?

Tags: time-series, correlation, trend

I'm having difficulty understanding if I can use a correlation if time is involved.

I have two sets of data on a particular country - **health** and **data** e.g. 10 years incidence of malaria and 10 years external health funding.

Does it make sense to calculate a correlation between these two values?

Comment: You could look at the trend in each (correlation with respect to time) or you could look at the relationship between the two variables assuming you have measurements taken at the same time and can therefore create a data point comprised of each measurement. However in the latter time will not be a factor.

Comment: Take the year-over-year values and compute the correlation, i.e. each value divided by the prior year's value.

Comment: Well, it might make sense, but a better analysis should be possible  (but only ten years of data is little) ... the first question you should ask yourself, is if there might be some other variable which might cause a correlation (econmic growth? population growth?) ...